# swift - How can I reach 2nd tab navigation stack from 1st tab?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a `TabBarController` with 2 tabs, and each of them is `NavigationController` with `UIViewController`s.

And, when I do some action at the 1st tab, I need be able to move one of `UIView`s on the 2nd tab to the top of the stack.

How can I reach 2nd tab navigation stack from 1st tab?

I don't want switch to 2nd tab, only move its `UIview` to the top of its stack

p.s. for example,

```
    TabbarController
       Tab1
         NavigationController1
          ViewController1
          ViewController2
       Tab2
         NavigationController2
          ViewController3
```

so from `ViewController3` be able to put `ViewController2` to the top of the stack `NavigationController1`

Comment: Do you want to show 2nd tab? Or do you just need to change stack of navigation controller in second VC?

Comment: @RobertDresler just change stack, without routing

Comment: Without clicking anywhere you want to go to the second tab? @nastassia

Comment: self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0 you can implement like this @nastassia 0 is your 2nd tab then you can directly move to your viewController1

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav I don't want move to 2nd tab, only move its UIview to the top of its stack

Comment: @nastassia check my edited answer

Comment: @RobertDresler your solution works great, why did you delete post? thank you so much anyway!

Comment: @nastassia oh! I'm glad! I tried in my code and it'd not worked because I'd tried it with wrong index of tab... :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `ViewController3` get reference for navigation controller embed in first tab (`NavigationController1`) and then try to downcast it as `UINavigationController`. Then just call `popToRootViewController(animated:)` on this navigation controller

```
if let navigationController = tabBarController?.viewControllers?[0] as? UINavigationController {
    navigationController.popToRootViewController(animated: true) // or `animated: false`
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this helps you!!

```
self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
```